# QField imported project location on Android

Tags: qgis, android, qfield

Using Qfield 2.0.14 on Android 12.

I manually transferred a QField project to my phone. I opened QField and used "Import Project from Folder". I have edited the project and can see the updates are there in QField.

But I can't find the project on my phone to transfer it back to my PC. I can see the Imported Projects location, which is

> /storage/emulated/0/android/data/ch.opengis.qfield/files/Imported Projects

But when I navigate to /android/data it is empty.

Does anyone know how to get this project back from my phone onto my PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to new google policies we,  unfortunately, had to remove some storage access functionalities and use the QField private folder. This folder is only available to QField.
the next QFiel version will have even better import/export functionality.

you can find many more details here: https://www.opengis.ch/2022/03/05/qfield-users-sit-down-we-need-to-talk-about-storage-access-on-android

Answer (score 0):

The folder is visible from windows when accessed via a USB cable, just not when browsing from a file explorer on the phone.